# Check the URL path using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

In my project, the gems that I've used are: rails admin, cancancan and devise.When I do the bundle install, lots of views will be added. I added "can :crud, [xxxx, xxxxx]" to have a CRUD in my ability model.

Question: How do I check the current path in my view? because I want to disable some field. Example: I am in the new path method and have 3 fields for that(then I clicked the submit/create, now it will the added data). I clicked the edit button,then there's one field will be disabled.

Note: The both form of new path and edit path is in the same file(activities_types/_form.html.erb).

**View**

_Form.html.erb

```
  <% if current_page?(new_activity_type_path) %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
<% else %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :"name" %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, disabled: true %>
  </div>
 <% end %>


  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
```

Comment: have you checked my posted answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to diffenetiate between edit and new actions in view then

```
<% if params[:action] == "new" %>
  ...
<% elsif params[:action] == "edit" %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

OR

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <% if params[:action] == "new" %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <% else %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, disabled: true %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is definitely a better way to go. I wasn't aware of `params[:action]`, thank you.

Comment: @Dithanial there is one more way ie @obj.new_record?

Comment: Actually sir @puneet18, I tried the .ne_record? It didnt work.. I also tried to delete some of my field, it didnt delete.. What do you think the problem?(I also refresh the page and restart the rails server)

Comment: @Angel whats the issues you faced?

Comment: The issues that im facing is, I think it didn't update when I changed anything

Comment: you cant update the name field on edit action because its disabled.

Comment: if you add value in name field by js then you have to make it read-only rather than diabled.

Answer (score 1):

I would set up an instance variable in your `new` and `edit` methods in your controller, following that up by checking the value in your form.

example:

```
def new
  @whereAmI = "new"
end

def edit
  @whereAmI = "edit"
end
```

In the view:

```
<% if @whereAmI == "edit" %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, disabled: true %>
<% elsif @whereAmI == "new" %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Sir I tried that but it didnt work.. I also tried to delete some of my field, it didnt delete.. What do you think the problem?(I also refresh the page and restart the rails server)

Answer (score 1):

You can check the action like this:

```
if params[:action] == "new"
 # doing something
elsif params[:action] == "edit"
 # doing something
end
```